# Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://0.0.0.0:9090

Tags: flutter, websocket, ros

I'm trying to connect to a Ros WebSocket service at ws://local host:9090 (runned with rosbridge) from my flutter application, but i'm getting the following error in Flutter:

> Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://local host:9090

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the **AndroidManifest.xml** file in the **android/app/src/main** folder.

Then set **usesCleartextTraffic** to **true**.

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...   >
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of permission and set android:usesCleartextTraffic to true

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
                android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
                android:label="receipt"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As [Aia Ashraf said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237547) you must add internet permission to your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

2. Please add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your both `AndroidManifest.xml` files in `yourapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml.`, and `yourapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.` like below:

   ```
   <application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...   >
   ```
3. And the last thing is to be sure that your windows firewall is turned off.

Here is Flutter documentation about this question:

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android