# error : Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have updated flutter version but when I run the project it throws this error when I call api

this is the error:

```
error : Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://****/user
```

***Note:*** This project was running well on old flutter version

how can I fix it??

Comment: Have you tried to use `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I can't use https because our server does not support security

Comment: This message is for the device not your server. I had the same problem with a website working with HTTP, so I used HTTPS in their URL and it worked, it was a workaround, maybe it can be of help in your case.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Ok I will try it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could be duplicate [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237338/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform-http-0-0-0-09090)

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file in the android/app/src/main folder.

Then set usesCleartextTraffic to true.

```
  <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...   >
```

for iOS add below code to *ios/Runner/info.plist*

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: you can have a look for those solutions. https://fluttercorner.com/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform-in-a-flutter/