# Cant send a post request to my api with flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter

I am trying to make a post request to my api to create a new user. My api works and I tried everything that I could find. The output is: `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/register`

I am using an android emulator I tried to use on my android phone it didn't work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://0.0.0.0:9090](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237338/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform-http-0-0-0-09090)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow HTTP request (it's by default disabled), you have to add this code in application tag in android manifest file:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

and for iOS view info.plist as source code and add this code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Yeah it didn't work... I tried any I could find on the wed nothing solved the problem...